# How do you get your question noticed?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Not sure if this is the right place, to ask, but on Stack Overflow I asked a question, and no one has answered. Not sure if I'm just being impatient, or if that's normal?

Just a newbie to these forums. And would it be ironic if no one noticed this question.

I have no rep (well I have 1 :P) so a bounty isn't going to work.

How am I going to get someone to answer?? (Wouldn't it be ironic if no one found this question...)